# How to use If inside NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, core-data

Is it possible to use `if` inside `NSPredicate`? In my `Student` table there is one column `sex` (male/female). I want to use two queries for male and female.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"if(sex=='male') query1  Else query2" ];
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AND` and `OR` to achieve this:

```
(sex = 'male' AND <query1>) OR (sex != 'male' AND <query2>)
```